# How to mathematically define a region in polar coordinate?

Tags: polar-coordinates

I want to define a region in polar coordinate, specified only with angle (i.e. radius doesn't matter). The region I want to show is plotted in the photo below and the boundary is $\cos^{-1}(x)$. How should I write this in mathematical format? [The region I want to describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4aPq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you take your angle to be $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$, the region you have drawn is described by
$$
\begin{align}
&\theta \leq \cos^{-1}(x) \\\text{ OR } \quad 
&\pi-\cos^{-1}(x) \leq \theta \leq \pi + \cos^{-1}(x)\quad \\
\text{ OR }\quad 
&2 \pi - \cos^{-1}(x) < \theta.
\end{align}
$$
If you are satisfied with an inequality that is not solved for $\theta$, we could describe the region with 
$$
|\cos \theta| \geq x. 
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Omnomnomnom for your answer. Is there a more compact form?

Comment: You could instead use two intervals if you allow angles to be taken from $-\pi/2 \leq \theta < 3\pi/2$, or one interval if you do this *and* allow for negative values of $r$.  However, in the standard version of polar coordinates, this cannot be made more compact.

Comment: We could also present this more compactly if we don't need to solve for $\theta$; see my latest edit.

Comment: Yes, This updated version is even better. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made a bit of a mistake there, see my latest edit.